# Python script that checks the same sheet in 300 xlsx files, compares it to a master sheet and updates it accordingly

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I have a list of around 300 excel files, all named following this pattern `[aA-zZ]{1}[0-9]{5}.xlsx`  and a master file. I'm trying to put together a python script that reads the same sheet/column in each file, compares it to the master's file sheet and updates it accordingly.

I've been trying openpyxl but I'm hopelessly stuck, any help is very much appreciated.

```
#!Python3
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os

# Move to the correct location
path = "/usr/tmp/files"
os.chdir(path)

# First we open the master file
wb = load_workbook('master.xlsx')

# grab master worksheet in master.xlsx
ws = wb.active('Sheet1')

#Second we open the rest of the files that include changes and compare with the data in master.xlsx

def main():
    for f in files:
        wb2 = load_workbook(f)
        ws2 = wb2['Sheet1']
    #read first workbook to get data
    wb2 = load_workbook(filename = '.xlsx')
    ws2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Sheet1')

#Iterate through worksheet and compare with master sheet for changes
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
           cellContent = str(cell.value)
           if cellContent == 'yes'
           wb = load_workbook('master.xlsx', optimized_write=True)
# Update cell contents
            ws[cell] = cellContent

# Save workbook
wb.save('master.xlsx')
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Thanks!!

!!!!!EDITED CODE!!!!!

```
#!Python3
From openpyxl import *
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

# Move to the correct location
path = "/usr/tmp/files"
os.chdir(path)

# First we open the master file
wb = load_workbook('master.xlsx')
# grab master worksheet in master.xlsx
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

# Open the rest of the files that include changes and compare with the data in master.xlsx

def main():
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if re.match(r'[A-Za-z][0-9]{5}\.xlsx', f)]
#read each workbook to get data
    for f in files:
        wb2 = load_workbook(f)
        ws2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
#Iterate through worksheet and compare with master sheet for changes
    for row in ws2.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            cellContent = str(cell.value)
            if cellContent == "yes":
                wb = Workbook(write_only = True)
# Update cell content
                ws[cell.coordinate] = str(cellContent)
             else:
                 continue

# Save workbook
wb.save('master.xlsx')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are there any errors, or is it just not working as you expect?

Comment: I'm stuck at the point where I need to iterate through all the 300 files and compare to the master file. Files are about 5MB each, hence I believe loading each file's data sheet in memory might make more sense than loading 300 wb but I'm lost there, thanks!

Comment: Instead of opening the workbooks, can you use `with workbook...`? I'm a little out-of-practice with Python/Excel, but I know for using, say, csv files it's "better" to use `with open("mycsv.csv") as file:` since it automatically closes it when it's done.  Or, just add a line that closes each workbook when done, so it's not stuck in memory when it's not needed?

Comment: In this line `for f in files:`: `files` looks like it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the files I'd be tempted to do this in two steps: first read in the files in read-only mode and identify whether they need correcting or not.

Then go through the list of the files that need correcting and update only these. This is probably the fastest way to do this because it stops you loading all the worksheets of all the workbooks into memory.

NB. the syntax you're using is for older versions of openpyxl and no longer supported. I **strongly** advise you update to >= 2.4 and refer to the [official documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html) first and foremost.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have ammended the code and I get a new error when updating the cell in the master file, see below:

Comment: `File "combine.py", line 31, in main
ws[cell] = str(cellContent)
 File "/environments/my_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxlworksheet/worksheet.py", line 380, in __setitem__
self[key].value = value
File "/environments/my_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 357, in __getitem__
 min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)
 File "/environments/my_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/utils/cell.py", line 127, in range_boundaries
m = ABSOLUTE_RE.match(range_string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: `cell` is the cell object. You might want `cell.coordinate` here but the code still looks odd, especially the use of write-only mode, which I didn't suggest.

Comment: write-only mode is used to when opening master.xlsx to be edited. Also, the only file that needs to be updated is master.xlsx, the updates are the differences between each of the data files and the master file

Comment: You **cannot** edit a file in write-only mode. As it stands the code makes little sense. NFT

Answer (score 0):

To get the matching files, first:

```
import re
```

then in the first line of `main()` define `files`:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if re.match(r'[A-Za-z][0-9]{5}\.xlsx', f)]
```

Note: I changed your regex pattern on the assumption that the filenames of interest are one letter (upper or lower case) followed by 5 digits followed by '.xlsx'.

Hope that helps